# How to set up a node to V7 Hard fork in testnet?

Tags: monerod, hard-fork, monerod-commands

I need to test an app running a node in V7 on testnet, avoiding Bulletproofs so i can have a clean v7 blockchain.
I have a node based on Master's code running on testnet but in some point starts to accept v8 hard fork blocks.

Is there an option or command to set the node to V7 hard fork and ignoring all v8 blocks?